# Correction of a proof

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

it would be nice, if someone could take a view on the following proof.

Let f be continuous, $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$. The integration area is $[a,t]\times[a,t]$ and i want to show that 
$$\int_a^t\int_a^\tau (t-\tau)^{-\alpha}(\tau-\xi)^{k-1}f(\xi)d\xi d\tau=\int_a^t\int_\xi^t (t-\tau)^{-\alpha}(\tau-\xi)^{k-1}f(\xi) d\tau d\xi$$
is valid.

The only thing which is changing is the integration direction of the inner integral, so the equation should be true.

I tried a induction proof. For $k=1$ one can show, that the equation is true. 
Now i consider $k \to k+1$ 
$$\int_a^t\int_a^\tau (t-\tau)^{-\alpha}(\tau-\xi)^{k}f(\xi)d\xi d\tau=\int_a^t\int_a^\tau (t-\tau)^{-\alpha}(\tau-\xi)^{k-1}(\tau-\xi)f(\xi)d\xi d\tau$$
$(\tau-\xi)f(\xi)$ is again continuous and i use the induction assumption and get 
$$\int_a^t\int_\xi^t (t-\tau)^{-\alpha}(\tau-\xi)^{k}f(\xi) d\tau d\xi$$
I am not sure at the step where i consider $(\tau-\xi)f(\xi)$ as a new function.

I would be glad about one ore two comments about this proof, or an alternative way to show the equality. 
It should be true, since Igor Podlubny use this equation in his book Fractional Differential Equations on page 67, but he did not made any comments about it.

Thanks, Matthias

Comment: Since the integrands are the same on both side, assume the integrand is well behaved so that the order of integration $\int d\tau$ and $\int d\xi$ is valid, all we need to check is the domain of integrations are the same.  And indeed the integrations are over the same domain on the $\xi-\tau$ plane.  It is a triangle of $(a,a), (a,t), (t,t)$.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. In this  way i thought about the problem  to convince myself, but i want to write it down rigorously to learn some ways and tricks for such problems and for the future. Is there a way to write it down correctly and is my induction proof correct? Thanks

Comment: I don't think you need induction.  How did you prove the equality for $k=1$?

Comment: I use the partial integration and Fubini on both sides. The part which make problems, concerning the partial integration,  for k>1is $(\xi-\tau)$. For k=1 it does not appear.